# How to remove/hide icons in com.1gravity:android-contactpicker:1.0.6?

Tags: android, contactpicker

Hi I use 1gravity:android-contactpicker:1.0.6 library to pick multiple contacts from my phone. Here I don't want search feature.How to remove/hide search feature in this library? Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding library using gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.1gravity:android-contactpicker:1.0.6'
}
```

You won't be able to edit the library, in other words, it is only read-only.

**Solution:**

> Download the whole project or clone it.
>
> Import the 'library' as a library in android studio,

Now you can edit the library to meet your requirements!